# elementary OS not detecting my OS (Windows 10)

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot

I currently have Windows 10 on my ssd and I shrunk my C partition, created ElementaryOS usb, booted through usb and elementary OS isn't giving me to install it as a dual boot. It says "no detected operating system" and the other option is to "do something else" which I'm not completely confident in. I searched around and many people recommended using fixparts in Try-mode but fixparts is giving back some grim looking errors. If I run:

```
sudo fixparts /dev/sda
```

It says `Warning: 0xEE partition doesn't start on sector 1. This can cause problems in some OSes.` After I inputted "W" for the command that was suggested and I get "Final checks complete. About to write MBR data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING PARTITIONS!!".

Should I be worried at all about the errors? I stopped myself from going forward and cancelled the command because I felt like it would destroy my Windows 10 partition and everything would go to hell. I can provide as much information as possible if it can lead to some solution. I installed ElementaryOS on my laptop in a breeze choosing the "Install alongside them" option.

If I run `sudo parted /dev/sda print` I get back

- 1 1049kb 525MB 524MB primary ntfs boot
- 2 525MB 323GB 322GB primary ntfs

When I shrunk the partition, I remember shrinking it from roughly 450GB to 300GB somewhere around there. I hope the information helps in looking at my problem. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Is this system UEFI?

Comment: Thanks to your information I think you have created a efi bootdisk, you should try to recreate your USB bootdisk with rufus (Windows software) it allons you to create uefi USB bootdisk

Answer (score 1):

1. choose something else
2. Create a ext4 partition for root
3. Also create a swap area
4. And process to installation